# instantiating Two arrays from two text files

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I am trying to instantiate the String array cool with items from the file "cool.txt" and the same for the array warm except with the text file "warm.txt" the program works to an extent however many elements of the array are labeled as null like this [image]

This is partially correct as they array has all the correct items; just millions of null's after

here is my code

```
 int count2=0;
   int count3=0;
   String[] filename ={"Cool.txt","Warm.txt"};
   String[] cool =new String[30];
   String[] warm =new String [3000];
   String[][] arrays = new String [][]{cool,warm};
   BufferedReader fr;



  try
  {
   for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
   fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename[i]));
  String line = fr.readLine();

   while (line != null)
          {

                if (i<=0)
              {arrays[i][count2]=line;
              System.out.println("COOL");    
              count2++;}

      if(i>=1)
      {arrays[i][count3]=line;
      System.out.println("WARM");    
      count3++;}

      line = fr.readLine();

}
  fr.close();


    }

   System.out.println(Arrays.asList(warm));
   System.out.println(Arrays.asList(cool));
  }




          catch(Exception F){
       System.out.println("NUL");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an array of objects in Java, they are initialized to a default value. For integers, this is 0. For Objects, such as String, this is a null-reference. As your array is made to contain 30000 elements, it will have the elements from your file (about 5), and the rest will not be initialized (null).

If you wish to use a list of Objects that has a variable size, you can look up ArrayLists, or other types of Lists. If you were to replace the following lines:

```
String[] cool =new String[30];
String[] warm =new String [3000];
```

and

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(warm));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(cool));
```

with

```
List<String> cool = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> warm = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and

```
System.out.println(warm);
System.out.println(cool);
```

You would get the correct result.
You were already using lists in a way: the method call `Arrays.asList` converts the argument to an object of the type List.

Comment: No problem! If you're using Java 7, you don't even need to repeat the 'String' in `new ArrayList<String>();`. You could simply write: `List<String> cool = new ArrayList<>();` and Java will find out what type it is supposed to be. That's called the diamond operator. It's useful to save some time by having to type less!

Comment: Yeah i am infact i just used a manual array print statement and left the arrays as type String

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the function you end up converting them to `list` objects.  If you just use a `List` to start with you won't have "millions" of nulls.  The reason why you get nulls is you can only allocate the array one time, so all slots are defaulted to `null`.